# Linux PCI driver read consolidation

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, fpga, pci

I have a PCI driver communicating with an FPGA. I am trying not to put DMA on the FPGA if it can be avoided, and I feel very close to achieving what I want: burst read/write speeds >20MB/s.

My design only uses one BAR, which I mapped with `ioremap_wc()` which made my write speeds top out at ~200MB/s which is the fastest my FPGA supports. However, my read speeds are only ~7MB/s. Both benchmarks made transferring 8KB.

My question is: Is there a Linux API call I am missing that can improve my read speeds, or must I implement DMA to get anything better than what I've shown above?

My driver is running on an ARM 64-bit processor: NXP iMX8

Edit:

I am mmap-ing my BAR in user space to interface with the FPGA's registers. Doing this, I had to disable caching since I would not always see the correct data in the BAR offsets when I read them.

Edit 2:
Here are some simplified code snippets of my implementation (hopefully they're helpful)

My driver's `_read()` function:

```
ssize_t driver_read(struct file *filp,
                     char __user *userBuf,
                     size_t len,
                     loff_t *offp)
{
...

    if (copy_to_user(userBuf, BAR.kvm_addr + *offp, len) != 0)
        return (-EFAULT);

    return (len);
}
```

My BAR ioremapping:

```
ioremap_wc(pBAR->pci_start, // PCI bus start address
           pBAR->len);      // BAR size
```

My call to `pread()` that I used to test

```
...
int fd = open("/path/to/driver", O_RDWR, 0666);
uint32_t *rxBuf = (uint32_t *)malloc(4 * 2048);
memset(rxBuf, 0x00, 4 * 2048);

pread(fd,
      rxBuf,
      4 * 2048,
      0);
...
```

Comment: What instructions are you using to read from the device? Each read operation requires a round-trip to the device, so if you’re doing 1-byte or 4-byte reads, it takes considerably more time than using 8-, 32-, or 64-byte reads.

Comment: I am using `pread()` in userspace, and my driver uses `copy_to_user()` inside its read file operation to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I think @prl is asking what you are using to read from device memory (e.g. `readb`, `readw`, readl`, `ioread8`, `ioread16`, `ioread32` or whatever), not what you are using to access user memory.

Comment: The PCI BAR I am trying to access is mapped into kernel memory, so I am using `copy_to_user(userBuf, BAR.kvm_addr, len)` to read from device memory. Perhaps that is my mistake? I tried to find n-bit variants of that function, but as far as I could tell from the Linux source code, there's just the one function that almost immediately becomes ARM assembly.

Comment: Although I’m not familiar with the implementation, I’m sure copy_to_user is optimized for reading from DRAM and not reading from a PCI device.

Comment: @prl, if that's the case, are you familiar with any examples that can do large reads at higher speeds? I experimented with `readq` but still was not getting any noticeable performance increases. I tried to find more detailed information based on your first comment, but to no avail. Thank you for helping!

Comment: I don’t know anything about ARM. On x86, I would try using AVX512 to get 64-byte loads. Or MOVDIR64B (although that has special behavior that may make it worse for this purpose). Both of those have limited availability, so 32-byte AVX may be more practical.

Comment: PCIe supports up to 512  byte transfers, so DMA is really what you want.

Comment: As to add to what @prl said, I'm in doubt how practical modern PCI device can be w/o DMA. If you need MSI, you must have DMA, and so on. WRT `copy_to_user()` use in the code, it's an abuse actually of it, you are kinda lucky to get something meaningful out of that, because under the hood it uses some `mov` (x86 term) or `ldr` (arm term) CPU opcode which is able to read MMIO. But I have no idea what would be the side effects on ARM. Basically you have to have a dedicated buffer before supplying it to user space.

Comment: Ok, taking in what everyone's said, it sounds like DMA really is the only way to go. The speed bump I got from `ioremap_wc()` seems to have given me the false sense that I could get away without DMA and just do large transfers to/from a BAR offset, which is not the case. Thanks everyone. @0andriy specifically made this clear, if you could post your explanation as the answer that would be great.

Comment: Just an example why usual mem operations are wrong against MMIO: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/ulfh/mmc.git/commit/?h=fixes&id=103a5348c22c3fca8b96c735a9e353b8a0801842.